# what error prevents my callback from executing often?

Tags: javascript, php, angularjs

I am working on a project angularjs version 1.7.8 with php server side. I integrated a javascript script in my template that I use in my controller. In this script I have a callback function after which I make a redirection to another application. My problem is that often the callback function runs and often no but no error is reported when it does not work. here is my code:

//built-in script function in angularjs

```
function redirect(montant,callb){
    //I encripte information
    var dataEncrypt="51565445656040445666640666906565665606";
    var id="test";
    //function callback
    callb(id);
    //redirect site
    window.location = 'http://monSite.com/template/index.php?test='+dataEncrypt;
}

//controller angularjs

redirect(montant,function (id){      
    $http.post('php/execution.php', {
        data1: montant, data2: id, data3: $scope.data3, dat4: $scope.data4, data5: $scope.data5
    })
    .then(function success(e) {

    }, function error(e) {

    });
});
```

My PHP code:

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), TRUE);
$data1=$data['data1'];
$data2=$data['data2'];
$data3=$data['data3'];
$data4=$data['data4'];
$data5=$data['data5'];
$insererTransaction = $infos_connexion->prepare("insert into transaction (id,data1,data2,data3,data4,data5)
values(:id,:data1,:data2,:data3,:data4,:data5)");
$resultat_inserTransaction=$insererTransaction->execute(array(":id" => NULL, ":data1" => $data1, ":data2" => $data2, ":data3" => $data3, ":data4" => $data4, ":data5" => $data5));
```

I expected that every time the process is followed, an insertion is done in my database,but it doesn't always happen. Sometimes it does, sometimes it does not, just randomly.

Comment: Not sure if you should pass `":id" => NULL` to the execute as you have no bind variable for it in your SQL.

Comment: You are redirecting at the same time as you are calling the callback function. Not sure what you want to do here ? You probably want to make the redirect in the success function

Comment: no, i want to execute in this way

Comment: i want that my callback execute the AJAX request

Comment: Nigel Ren it is a mistake but realy it well implemented

Comment: Because Ajax calls are **asynchronous**, your function doesn't wait for the Ajax to run before it starts the redirect. Do depending how fast the server responds to the Ajax request Vs the redirect request will probably determine whether your functionality works as intended. Execute the redirect in the .then() callback if you want this to be reliable...that's what it's there for.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your statement "In this script I have a callback function after which I make a redirection to another application." is actually not true. You are making the redirect at the exact same time you are calling the callback function. You will probably have unpredictable behavior.

What you probably want to do is to redirect after your ajax call :

```
redirect(montant,function (id){      
    $http.post('php/execution.php', {
        data1: montant, data2: id, data3: $scope.data3, dat4: $scope.data4, data5: $scope.data5
    })
    .then(function success(e) {
        var dataEncrypt="51565445656040445666640666906565665606";
        //redirect site
        window.location = 'http://monSite.com/template/index.php?test='+dataEncrypt;
    }, function error(e) {

    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but the redirect function is from a different javascript file, how can i manage that ?